# $lookup giving me an "unknown error" in mongodb's aggregation builder tool

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas, nosql-aggregation

I'm trying to enrich an id that's in an array by adding a $lookup step to the end of an existing aggregate pipeline that works. I'm trying this out in MongoDB aggregate builder but it just says "An unknown error occurred" with this $lookup. what could the error be?

```
$lookup
{
  from: 'people',
  as: 'history.person',
  foreignField: 'person_id',
  localField: 'history.person_id'
}
```

history has an array of objects, each containing person_id. i read that $lookup can handle arrays.

The data looks like this

people collection:

```
...
person_id: 1
...
```

aggregate results prior to error $lookup:

```
...
history : Array
    0: Object
        person_id: 1
    1: ...
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:
I found the issue out! The syntax was fine. Apparently, the results of the $lookup were too big, and exceeded some size limit. I just wish the MongoDB atlas aggregate builder tool would have told me that!